# changing if/else-statements within gui components in java

Tags: java, string, user-interface

if I had a `JTextArea` or something like that, would it be possible to send a `String` variable to my source code which changes the conditions of a if-statement?

This would be my source code:

```
if(condition1 + operation + condition2){
  // do something
}
```

And in my GUI I had three TextAreas:

```
[Condition1]: "array[i]"  or "(array[i]+array[i+1])/2"   // what ever
[Operator]:   "<"           // or >, !=, etc
[Condition2]: "array[i-1]"
```

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to evaluate a string as if it is source code. It is not, so that approach (apart from being potentially insecure) won't work.
You could map your conditions and operands to an enum like this :

```
public static enum ECondition {
    EQ,NE,LT,GT,LE,GE
}
public static enum EVariables {
    MY_ARRAY, MY_OTHER_VAR
}

public void eval(ECondition myCondition, EVariables myVar, String myIndex) {
    ...

    if(myVar.equals(EVariables.MY_ARRAY)) {
        doSometingToMyArrayAtIndex(myCondition,Integer.parseInt(myIndex), Object /* whatever type it is*/ myReferenceValue);
    } else if(myVar.equals(EVariables.MY_OTHER_VAR)) {
        doSometingToMyOtherVar(myCondition);
    }
}

public void doSometingToMyArrayAtIndex(ECondition cond, Integer index, Object myReferenceValue) {
    boolean isConditionTrue = false;
    switch(cond) {
        case EQ:
            isConditionTrue = (myArray[index] == myReferenceValue);
            break;
        case NE:
            isConditionTrue = (myArray[index] != myReferenceValue);
            break;
      // ... and so on
    }
}
```

the other approach would be to use a code parser, but i wouldn't recommend that. Apart from security, I think it would be overkill.
But, if you want to explore the parser approach, take a look at this :
https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser

Comment: thank you. perfect! and sorry for my cryptic language

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit cryptic, but yes you could have something like that. The issue however, is that you would need to find a way to *parse* whatever it is that the user will have provided.

You would need to establish some sort of *grammar* which people using your program would need to follow to ensure that they provide strings which your program can work with.

You will also need to provide some sort of dictionary which would expose which operations can be performed so that your application would know which character would resolve to what mathematical operator.